# Alter http response body of apache in Java

Tags: java, apache, proxy

I serve a localhost using apache. And I have a browser which sends requests to the apache server and gets response from the apache.

Now I want to design a Java program that can intercept the http response body echoed from the apache and modify it before arriving to the browser.

I did some homework and saw that webscarab may be useful. However, I did not find any tutorial/examples to start with programmatically using the webscarab.

Anyone has any idea on this? Any concrete examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to modify the response for some of the users, or all of the user?

Comment: @PradeepPati Doesnt matter I guess. Maybe I just need to set up a http proxy programmatically and connect my browser(say firefox) to that proxy. Then the proxy does some work that I want on each response received. Any ideas?